# zeromq working for phpcli, but not for apache

Tags: php, apache, zeromq

First of all, I checked all related questions, but in my case it must be something else (I tried the solutions from there);

I installed zeromq following these instructions http://zeromq.org/bindings:php and everything works just fine when I run my php script from CLI

Problem is running from apache server, I get the

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZMQContext' not found in /var/www/i.php on line 19
```

line 19 is

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
```

What I tried:

1)I ran the php_info(), I found out where my php.ini files are

```
 /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-php_pdo_mysql.ini, 
 /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-zmq.ini,
 and so on...
```

So I opened these files and add line "extension=zmq.so"

Did not help.

2)I added following lines to the beginning of my script:

```
use \ZMQContext;
use \ZMQ;
```

Again, did not help

3) I checked the apache error logs and find this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626
/zmq.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/zmq.so:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626
/zmq.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/zmq.so: cannot open shared object file: No such 
file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

4) So I checked, where the zmq.so actually is on my machine:

```
user@wb:~$ sudo find / -name zmq.so
/home/user/php-zmq/modules/zmq.so
/home/user/php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so
/var/www/push/php-zmq/modules/zmq.so
/var/www/push/php-zmq/.libs/zmq.so
/usr/lib/php5/20100525/zmq.so
/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/zmq.so
```

---

So do you have any suggestion what else might be wrong? Thank you

Comment: You did restart Apache after editing the config files, right?

Comment: yes yes, I restarted apache zillion times

Comment: Do you see anything in the error logs? Sometimes a module cannot be loaded due to binary incompatibility.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I forgot about that, there was something in the error logs - I've edited the original question

Comment: Looks like the extension is not installed at all. Did you follow the [installation instructions](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php)? Do you actually have a file named `zmq.so` somewhere?

Comment: yes yes, I followed them and it is actually working for my script if I run it with PHP-CLI, I can also find zmq.so on several places on my machine

Comment: Right, you mentioned that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solve it out (thaks to lxg for pointing me to the right direction)

First of all I have to manually remove my compiled versions of apache and php (following some tutorials here on SO)

then removing php and apache with apt-get

reinstalling php and apache with apt-get

reinstalling zmq (compile and do php bindings)

I don't have the latest php and apache, but at least the module is loaded both in Apache and in php CLI

Answer (score 2):

I have to take a few guesses, but let's give it a try:

You appear to have different versions of PHP installed, or you have updated/downgraded your PHP.

You have the folder `/usr/lib/php5/20100525/` on your system which belongs to PHP 5.4 on a Debian-type machine (I think). But your PHP looks for the file in `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/`, which I think belongs to PHP 5.3.

Your PHP CLI seems to run with PHP 5.4, while the `mod_php` of your Apache appears to run 5.3.

If this is true, you can try copying the `zmq.so` into `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/zmq.so/` and restart Apache. But it could fail due to binary incompatibility, if it was built against PHP 5.4.

In this case, I'd recommend to upgrade your `mod_php` to PHP 5.4 (again?).

Comment: yes, this might be it, apache php is using PHP Version 5.3.10 and CLI php is using v 5.5.4, could you navigate me, how to upgrade mod_php? (I tried  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and so on, but the apache php version is still the same)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is something I can't do from remote, knowing barely anything about your system. But, if you've managed to set up PHP 5.5 for CLI, then usually you should also be able to install mod_php the same way (or already have it, and only need to switch).

Comment: Sorry, but I helped as good as I could (and I guess that it's kind of a solution; at least you know now why it isn't working). I think you should ask a new question, and maybe better on http://superUser.com than here. Folks there are more familiar with that type of problem. I'd suggest that you include as much information as possible about how you managed to end up with two different PHP versions.

Comment: yes sure, I'm sorry if it sounded ungrateful :-) Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all. By the way, you could accept this answer, if you feel that it helped you. ;)